# Include_once in Slim Framework, ruins the header

Tags: php, mamp, httpresponse, slim

I faced an issue, for several days now, where the response header on my very simple API, built with Slim Framework, returned `HTML/TEXT` instead of `APPLICATION/JSON` – no matter what I did.

I found out, that the problem could be solved if I removed my only `include_once` in the file; a file that contains some configuration variables, but writing everything in one file is not feasible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your include is outputting something that invalidates your json.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense - but it's just some arrays with configuration data...

Comment: `text/html` is the “default” content type PHP scripts send; so if your script tries to send another header, but doesn’t succeed, then this is likely a problem of your script generating any kind of output before calling `header` … proper error_reporting and debugging should be able to verify that, I’d expect a “headers already sent” warning to show up somewhere.

Comment: The configuration.php file, I include only contains of an `Array` with configuration details... it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Seriously - why are people downvoting this question? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should check the exact response, perhaps the problem is a utf8 BOM. I would guess the downvotes are because the question is not very useful without any additional information like the file in question as now we can only speculate.

Comment: The response header is fine if the code is written in one single file... If I extract the same code into two or three files, and include/include_once/require the other files, then the response is HTML.

Comment: Jeroen... I removed the BOM, which you suggested, and that fixed it. Thanks a bunch. Would you make that an answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove BOM from the file. `Include` a file with BOM apparently affects the response header somehow.